# How to override nuxt-link's default behavior?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, single-page-application

I'm working with nuxt 2 and I need to treat some requests as if my website was MPA not SPA. So, nuxt-link built-in component by default is navigating the user to different routes without refreshing the page.

How can I make nuxt-link component to act as a normal `<a>` if there is specific `.env` variable is true?

Comment: Are you sure there is no way to solve your MPA issue with something that we already have in Nuxt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: you can't do that, there is no such thing.

---

Nuxt is not able to do MPA efficiently, this is the wrong tool for such purpose.

`nuxt-link` is also based on `router-link`, aimed to be used in an SPA-only context. If you check [Vue router's API](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/api/), you'll see nothing like that because it's not what it's meant to be used for.
`nuxt-link` add some things on top of it, but still nothing related to an MPA behavior.
There is no setting like that in the framework overall because it's not behaving like NextJS. Nuxt is meant to be used as an SPA-only, SSR, SSG, Edge but not MPA.

If you want to have an MPA behavior and a lot of performance overall, I recommend using a regular Node.js or PHP server or even AstroJS: you'll be able to keep using Vue (+ it's reactivity) or even [îles](https://iles.pages.dev/).

---

To answer your question, if you **still** want to use Nuxt as an MPA for a specific reason, use `<a>`.

Comment: You could use a [Navigation Guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) to override the default behaviour.

But I agree, if you want a regular link, just use `<a>`

Comment: @Krillko you can do a lot of things with JS, the limit is how messy you want it mainly.

Comment: Sure, but in this case it's a part of Vue router so I'm going to assume that it's tested enough. Also we use navigation guard for various things in production, and to the best of my knowledge, it works fine

Comment: @Krillko getting out of the JS realm by using JS by nuking your SPA is all but a good pattern. You have a tags and vue-router links, both are serving totally different purposes. Hijacking one and transforming it into another is clearly feasible but not a good approach overall is all I'm saying. Especially because it will mess up all the lifecycle hooks once you have another initial render (after the window location change). So yeah, it's stable and that works but clearly not a recorded pattern in a codebase that I would suggest, not for that case at least.